# OData Service Definitions - ordering tables in .xsodata file

Tags: odata, hana, hana-xs

I'm new in SAP HANA and I'm trying to sort a table in .xsodata file. Is that possible?

Best regards.

Comment: What do you mean by 'order a table'? Do you want to provide data in a sorted fashion?

Comment: Yes, I want to to provide data in a sorted fashion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option to specify the sorting order in the odata service definition.
Usually, the ODATA client specifies the expected order via the $orderby URL parameter.

Comment: Is is possible to set NULLS LAST somehow?